# Remove a subset of records from a dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe

We can combine 2 dataframes using `df = rbind(df, another_df)`. How it should be if its required to remove `another_df` from `df` where rownames of `df` and `another_df` are not matching.

```
df = data.frame(A=c('a','aa','aaa'), B=c('b','bb','bbb'))
rownames(df)

another_df =data.frame(A=c('aa','a'), B=c('bb','b'))
rownames(another_df)=c('3','4')
```

Comment: Please show a reproducible small example and expected output.  I would check for `?setdiff` or `anti_join` from `dplyr`

Comment: Per comment above this may help you to make a good example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thanks akrun, anti_join from dplyr did the job :) I would like to accept as answer if you post it :)

Comment: I posted my comment as a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `anti_join`

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(df, another_df)
```

---

Or if this is based on the `rownames`, then `%in%` can be used for creating a logical index to subset the rows

```
df[!row.names(df) %in% row.names(another_df),]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using any package very easily with setdiff.

```
 df = data.frame(A=c('a','aa','aaa'), B=c('b','bb','bbb'))
 another_df =data.frame(A=c('aa','a'), B=c('bb','b'))
 s <- df[setdiff(rownames(df),rownames(another_df)),]
```

s is the output you want.